# AVERAGEIF and formulaR1C1 not combining correctly

Tags: vba

I'm very new to VBA, so this may be a basic question.  I've already checked through various posts here, and it seems that what I'm attempting to code should work, but doesn't.

```
Dim z as String                                                            
z = ">0"                                                     
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGEIF(R[-11]C[-3]:R[-1]C[-3]," & z & ")"
```

I'm trying to concatenate this, as when I write:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGEIF(R[-11]C[-3]:R[-1]C[-3],">0")"
```

it says that it "expected the end of statement".

Comment: Change it to `z = """>0"""` and it should work. The formula is expecting your condition to be a string and you have to escape the double-quote.

Comment: @PeterT That worked, thank you very much!